# Connection closed by remote host followed by Connection refused

Tags: linux, centos, ssh, centos5

All of a sudden my ssh connection to server has been damaged. Here is what's happened:

```
$ ssh -vvv -p <PORT> -l <USER> <HOST>
OpenSSH_5.3p1 Debian-3ubuntu7, OpenSSL 0.9.8k 25 Mar 2009
debug1: Reading configuration data /home/khosrow/.ssh/config
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: Applying options for *
debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to <HOST> [<IP>] port <PORT>.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/khosrow/.ssh/identity type -1
debug1: identity file /home/khosrow/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/khosrow/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
```

I've recently updated the box with `yum update` and sshd got updated as well. I honestly don't know if this caused any damages or not. But it's prompted that `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` was stored as `/etc/ssh/sshd_config.rpmnew` which was quite normal.

I've seen similar posts while googling, but almost all of them suggests that I should check `/etc/hosts.allow` and `/etc/hosts.deny`, which in my case, I can't. I can not connect to the box to see what's going on there.

I rebooted the box, through web interface of server provider, and it even got worse. I'm now getting this:

```
$ ssh -vvv -p <PORT> -l <USER> <HOST>
OpenSSH_5.3p1 Debian-3ubuntu7, OpenSSL 0.9.8k 25 Mar 2009
debug1: Reading configuration data /home/khosrow/.ssh/config
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: Applying options for *
debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to <HOST> [<IP>] <PORT>.
debug1: connect to address <IP> port <PORT>: Connection refused
ssh: connect to host <HOST> port <PORT>: Connection refused
```

with both `<CUSTOM_PORT>` and default 22 ports.

I would really appreciate if anyone could help me on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like sshd is down or iptables is blocking you. Maybe there's a problem with the configuration of sshd. What happens if you telnet the custom port and port 22?

Is telnet access enabled on your server? You can still try to access via telnet.

If you can't manage services or firewall from the web console or login via telnet, I'm afraid you have to call your provider customer support.

Comment: telneting custom port and port 22 is `telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused`. port 23 is `telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection timed out`. Do you think this could be result of some attacking?

Comment: It could be just a problem of configuration.

Comment: Thank you. You were absolutely right. When `sshd` updated, there was something wrong with old `GSSAPI` configurations.